# Avoiding foreach for @html.checkboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application using MVC. I had a requirement where I have to display checkbox for a list.

I was going through different posts for doing this, one of them is the use of avoiding foreach for looping and making use of @html.editorfor() as described in the answer by Darwin dimitrov [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652606/how-to-use-html-checkboxfor-while-dealing-with-a-listviewmodel):

This answer works fabulously fine, but I have a clarification , it is:

1. In the same view I have 2 requirements , the one with checkboxfor and the other one with radiobuttonfor
   So, If I am using

   `<div>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.RoleAccess)</div>`

How do I write the (~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RoleAccessViewModel.cshtml) to serve for checkboxfor for one requirement , and the other one for @radiobuttonfor .

Wont this approach be hardcoded which will always render the RoleAccessViewModel.cshtml whenever `EditorFor(x => x.RoleAccess)` is used?Please execuse me If I have used any technical terms wrong way,as I still a novice in mvc.

Comment: if i understood you question correctly . you are looking for a single view with a conditional display of `checkboxfor` and `radiobuttonfor` right ? then i advice you to use `ViewBag` which is reliable .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EditorFor` method has an overload that accepts a template name as argument. I think that solves your problem if I understand it correctly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: This looks like the right answer but it would be nice to see an example

Comment: Choose your poison wisely.  This solution allows a value on a model to change (from a radiobox to a checkbox) by the programmer with no default.  Technically it is easier to have UI inconsistencies to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this by using the `UIHint` attribute on your property instead (or in addition to) relying on naming the template after your view model. Then you can create an alternate template to render the radio buttons and specify that:

```
[UIHint("RadioList")]
public List<Something> MyRadioButtonList { get; set; }
```

`EditorFor` will then look for the template: `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\RadioList.cshtml`

You could do the same for your checkbox list, as well, instead of relying on the view model. For example, `[UIHint("CheckboxList")]` and `CheckboxList.cshtml`. Then, you'd be able to apply these templates more broadly.

Comment: Choose your poison wisely.  This solution supplies a default display type for the value.  It can be overridden if necessary, and documents at the model level what the value is trying to accomplish.  If overridden in a view, it can be difficult to debug because the view won't match what the model says the value is for.

Comment: True, but the same could be done with any application of something like `DataType` or even just relying on the C# type itself. Besides, within the context of a view model, this should be far less problematic, since the model is very literally designed for the view.

Comment: Totally agree, I simply was commenting on the pro/cons of each of the answers for the OP.