# List of checkboxes always null MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble with sending `checkboxes` and `EditorFor` values in MVC. I have two classes:

```
public class CompleteReceiving
 {
   public List<SiteOrderReceiving> order_detail { get; set; } //<- Data from DB. It contains all items for Order Receiving.
   public List<SomeClass> new_form { get; set; } //<- Fields for form
 }  

public class SomeClass
 {
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Receive Quantity can only contain number")]
        public decimal? receive_quantity { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Damaged Quantity can only contain number")]
        public decimal? damaged_quantity { get; set; }  

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my View:

```
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.order_detail.Count; i++)
     {  
      <tr> 
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.new_form[i].IsSelected, new { id = "site_rec_checkbox", @class= "site_rec_checkbox" })
       </td>  
       <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.new_form[i].receive_quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control fm", @autocomplete = "off", @autofocus = "autofocus", @placeholder = "Receiving Quantity" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.new_form[i].receive_quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </td>  
     }
```

And this is my Controller Action Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SiteOrderReceiving(CompleteReceiving sor)
 {
     //Code for post
 }
```

The problem is that whenever i select `checkbox` at any other `index` than `1` or `2` the `List` is always `null`. But for the first time if i select `3` or `4` and after that i select `1` or `2` than it works fine. 
I don't know what i am doing wrong here.
Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
This is my Controller `Action Code`

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult SiteOrderReceiving(int? order_id)
 {
   var get_detail = (from oa in db.order_send
                     where oa.order_id == order_id 
                     select new SiteOrderReceiving()
                     {
                       quantity_send = oa.send_quantity,
                       date_send = oa.send_date,
                       order_id = oa.order_id
                     }).ToList();
  var a = new CompleteReceiving();
  a.order_detail = get_detail;
  return View(a);
}
```

And this is my `View`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SiteOrderReceiving", "Site", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "receive_form" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.order_detail.Count; i++)
{  
 <tr> 
     <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.new_form[i].IsSelected, new { id = "site_rec_checkbox", @class= "site_rec_checkbox" })
     </td>  
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.new_form[i].receive_quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control fm", @autocomplete = "off", @autofocus = "autofocus", @placeholder = "Receiving Quantity" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.new_form[i].receive_quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </td>  
  }
```

}

Comment: I don't know whether this is related to your problem or not, but id should be unique. All your checkboxes have id = "site_rec_checkbox". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11652804/2131092 for an example of checkboxes in a for loop

Comment: @AndyNichols i managed to solve the problem. Can i answer my own question? Am i allowed to do that?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Not related, but you generating form controls for properties of `new_form`, therefore the loop in your view should be `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.new_form.Count; i++)`, not `Model.order_detail.Count`. And the code you have shown will bind correctly, so its something you have not shown causing your issue. In addition, your `[RegularExpression]` are pointless - the property is `decimal` which can only be a number. But `decimal` does not appear to make sense for a property that refers to a 'Quantity'  - an `int` seems more appropriate

Comment: @StephenMuecke but when i change my `view` to `Model.new_form.Count` it gives error of `Object reference not set to instance of an object`

Comment: You need to initialize and populate `new_form` with the items you want to edit

Comment: I am adding new record. And i am initializing and populating `order_detail`, but for data input i am using another class `new_form` as `List`. This is the reason why i have 2 `Lists` in my main class. I don't know if it's the right way, but it was working fine until this problem occurred. I still can't figure out why is that.

Comment: No its not the 'right' way :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the question and added more detail. Please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: You own answer is fine - because now you just have one collection property (`order_detail`) and you loop through that to add the for controls for properties of each item (looping through one collection to generate controls for different collection made no sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So i can accept my own answer now?

Comment: Yes, and you just have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i solved my problem. What i did was move properties of my `form` to existing class in which i was getting the data from `DB`.
Now my `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class CompleteReceiving
{
  public List<SomeClass> order_detail { get; set; }  
  //Some Other properties
}
```

And then:

```
public class SomeClass
{  
   [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Receive Quantity can only contain number")]
   public decimal? receive_quantity { get; set; }

   [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Damaged Quantity can only contain number")]
   public decimal? damaged_quantity { get; set; }  

   public bool IsSelected { get; set; }    

   public string item_name { get; set; }
}
```

After updating my `code` like above, everything started working fine. Hope it helps someone in the future.