# EditorFor is not submitted in FormPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, editorfortemplate

I have this ViewModels:
Inside "EMPRESA" I got a lot of properties that work just fine.

```
public class EmprViewModel
{
    public int ID_EMP { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }

    public List<TelasViewModel> Telas;
}

public class TelasViewModel
{
    public int ID_TELA { get; set; }
    public string TITULO { get; set; }
    public bool Valor { get; set; }
    public string Selecionado { get; set; }
}
```

My Razor is:

```
@model SYSTEMNAME.Models.EmprViewModel

<div class="container espaco">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarAlteracao", "Empresas", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmEmpresas" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_EMP)

    <div class="row">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Telas)
    </div>
}
```

And I created in ~\Shared\EditorTemplates\TelasViewModel.cshtml

```
@model SYSTEMNAME.Models.TelasViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID_TELA)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TITULO)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Selecionado)

<div class="cols3-25"><label>@Model.TITULO: </label></div>
<div class="cols3-75">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Valor)</div>
```

The output code generated in Razor is fine, for each "Telas" Object I got something like this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="O campo ID_TELA deve ser um número." data-val-required="O campo ID_TELA é obrigatório." id="Telas_0__ID_TELA" name="Telas[0].ID_TELA" type="hidden" value="2">
<input id="Telas_0__TITULO" name="Telas[0].TITULO" type="hidden" value="Contatos">
<input id="Telas_0__Selecionado" name="Telas[0].Selecionado" type="hidden" value="">

<div class="cols3-25"><label>Contatos: </label></div>
<div class="cols3-75"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Valor é obrigatório." id="Telas_0__Valor" name="Telas[0].Valor" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Telas[0].Valor" type="hidden" value="false"></div>
```

But When I get the FormPost, the list comes "null"

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarAlteracao(EmpresaViewModel EmpresaAlterado)
{
...
// Here if I try anything with EmpresaAlterado.Telas, it say "Telas is null";

}
```

What I'm maybe doing wrong or forgeting in this code?

Edit:

I the Post, there It's posting twice the field "Valor" like:

```
... &Telas%5B0%5D.ID_TELA=2&Telas%5B0%5D.TITULO=Contatos&Telas%5B0%5D.Selecionado=selected&Telas%5B0%5D.Valor=true&Telas%5B0%5D.Valor=false&Telas%5B1%5D.ID_TELA=3&Telas%5B1%5D.TITULO=Usuarios&Telas%5B1%5D.Selecionado=selected&Telas%5B1%5D.Valor=true&Telas%5B1%5D.Valor=false& ...
```

Can it have something to do With the two fields that "CheckboxFor" is creating on the Html? Here the example:

```
<div class="cols3-75"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Valor é obrigatório." id="Telas_0__Valor" name="Telas[0].Valor" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Telas[0].Valor" type="hidden" value="false"></div>
```

Comment: Something is wrong, how come you never iterate the list? `@model SYSTEMNAME.Models.TelasViewModel` should be `@model List<SYSTEMNAME.Models.TelasViewModel>`

Comment: Got how to use from several places, every place just said to put "EditorFor", this htmlHelper iterates for me, the return is several CheckBoxes (like 20) and all of them are normal to me, like the example of the return I pasted.

The first example I got to make this comes from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652606/how-to-use-html-checkboxfor-while-dealing-with-a-listviewmodel

The answer of Darin Dimitrov in this question above.

Comment: The CheckBoxFor helper intentionally creates two input elements. One is a hidden form with a "false" value. This is done because a checkbox's value is only included in a form submission if it's checked. Without the hidden element, the POST would be missing the associated field, which causes issues with list-bound values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only public *properties* are filled, check out that `Telas` it's a public variable, not property

Changing to

```
public List<TelasViewModel> Telas { get; set; }
```

will fix the issue

Comment: Worked. I forgot of "{ get; set;}" So it was public, but not a Property just like you said.
Thanks a lot.